# profvis in R causing a fatal error

Tags: r, profiling, xts

I am currently trying to optimize a fairly lengthy function `foo`.  The internal function calls are mostly `lapply` and `sapply` on `xts` data.

I am using `assertthat` and `testthat` inside of these functions in attempt to debug and verify data being produced and passed.

The function runs outside of `profvis` perfectly fine, and the result is as expected.  None of my asserts fail nor do any of the tests.

However, when I wrap the identical call of `foo` in `profvis(foo(args))`, I am getting:

> "R encountered a fatal error.  The session was terminated"

When I run the function with debugging on stepping through line by line, nested call by nested call, the place where it FATALS keeps changing.  This makes me think there is something wrong with my installation, or some idiosyncratic issues with the new builds/packages I'm using.  Or possibly my system.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

**UPDATE 1**
When I call the function on my linux VM inside of `profvis`, it doesn't experience the same error as on the windows machine, so I presume it's one of the updates I have deployed in some package over the past weeks.  If anyone else has experienced similar issues and found a resolution, any help is appreciated before I wipe the R windows installation clean.

**UPDATE 2**
After uninstalling all of the packages associated with R, and only installing the necessary ones, the problem still exists sporadically.  It is able to run once fine, but then fails every successive time with the following errors:

- `"Error: Unable to establish connection with R session"`
- `"R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated"`

Comment: You say you're using xts, but your `sessionInfo()` output doesn't include xts. What version of xts and zoo are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I provided session info from a clean session after one of the encountered fatal errors.  But I had pulled 0.10-0 from github when I did the reinstall of all the user packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I resorted to was archiving all user installed packages and reinstalling only the ones that `foo` was dependent on.  I presume some recent package update that I had previously installed was causing namespace issues.  I restarted my machine and it has appeared to clear up the issue.  Will update this thread if the issue resurfaces.